# How to convert a series of JSON strings into one json file?

Tags: python, json

I am using python and json to construct a json file. I have a string, 'outputString' which consists of multiple lines of dictionaries turned into jsons, in the following format:

```
{size:1, title:"Hello", space:0}
{size:21, title:"World", space:10}
{size:3, title:"Goodbye", space:20}
```

I would like to turn this string of jsons and write a new json file entirely, with each item still being its own line. I would like to turn the string of multiple json objects and turn it into one json file. I have attached the code on how I got outputString and what I have tried to do. Right now, the code I have writes the file, but all on one line. I would like the lines to be separated as the string is.

```
for value in outputList:
    newOutputString = json.dumps(value)
    outputString += (newOutputString + "\n")

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for item in outputString.splitlines():
        json.dump(item, outfile)
        json.dump("\n",outfile)
```

Comment: It's not JSON so it's not a good idea to save it with the `.json` extension. It's json-lines

Comment: @roganjosh I have an empty json file titled, 'data.json'. I want to write that file using the data from outputString

Comment: @EnoGerguri I will try that, thank you!

Comment: What error occurs with what you have tried?

Comment: @supercool it makes no difference. As soon as you do `with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:`, that file is completely overwritten. And it isn't JSON

Comment: @EnoGerguri It does not separate the lines, but all of the data is on one line.

Comment: I think that he is calling json.dumps twice on the same value. Once when assigning ‘newOutputString’ then you call json.dumps in the already dumped data.

Comment: @EnoGerguri I see, but I believe it does include all the correct data, just not in separated lines

Comment: @supercool Try instead of ‘json.dumps(“\n”)’ do: ‘outfile.write(“\n”)’ and instead of ‘w’ when opening the file use ‘a’ and make sure the file is empty.

Comment: @EnoGerguri That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @supercool ok let me put it into an official answer.

Comment: @supercool if you are happy with my answer, please accept it to show that it answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM: when you `json.dump("\n",outfile)` it will always be written on the same line as `”\n”` is not recognised as a new line in json.

SOLUTION: ensure that you write a new line using python and not a json encoded string:

```
with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:  # We are appending to the file so that we can add multiple new lines for each of different json strings
for item in outputString.splitlines():
    json.dump(item, outfile)
    outfile.write("\n”)  # write to the file a new line, as you can see this uses a python string, no need to encode with json
```

See comments for explanation.

Please ensure that the file you write to is empty if you just want these json objects in them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` rows are not in actual json format if the properties do not come between double quotes.

This would be a proper json data format:

```
{"size":1, "title":"Hello", "space":0}
```

Having said that here is a solution to your question with the type of data you provided.

I am assuming your data comes like this:

```
outputList = ['{size:1, title:"Hello", space:0}',
'{size:21, title:"World", space:10}',
'{size:3, title:"Goodbye", space:20}']
```

so the only thing you need to do is write each `value` using the file.write() function

Python 3.6 and above:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for value in outputList:
        outfile.write(f"{value}\n")
```

Python 3.5 and below:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for value in outputList:
        outfile.write(value+"\n")
```

data.json file will look like this:

```
{size:1, title:"Hello", space:0}
{size:21, title:"World", space:10}
{size:3, title:"Goodbye", space:20}
```

**Note**: As someone already commented, your data.json file will not be a true json format ted file but it serves the purpose of your question. Enjoy! :)